# php sql statment for multiple conditions proper approch

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to write one function which return `sql` statement

like

```
function get_sql($name=0,$date_start=0,$date_end=0)
{

$addQuery=" where 1=1";           
          if($name>0)
        {
            $addQuery .=" and name=".$name;
        }


              if($date_start>0)
        {

            $addQuery.=" and date >=".$date_start;
        }

               if($date_end >0)
        {

            $addQuery.=" and date<=".$date_end;
        }

          $query="select * from TABLE_ARTICLE".$addQuery;

return $query;
}
```

> sorry guys for wrong syntax typing

i have two concerns about this function.

1. does this is proper approach or not?
2. does this function will work when date will be passed in `01/03/2012` format, as you can see i want result between two dates if both are selected and after first date or before end date ?

i mean does this is best way to get data from sql in dates?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off using implode

```
function get_sql($name=0,$date_start=0,$date_end=0)
{

    $whereClauses = array();         
    if($name>0)
    {
        $whereClauses[] = "name='$name'";
    }

    if($date_start>0)
    {
        $whereClauses[] = "date >='$date_start'";
    }

    if($date_end >0)
    {
        $whereClauses[] = "date<='$date_end'";
    }

    $query="select * from TABLE_ARTICLE";
    if( !empty( $whereClauses ) )
    {
        $query.= ' WHERE ' . implode( ' AND ', $whereClauses );
    }

    return $query;
 }
```

Note also that I have quoted all your values as none of them seem to be integer values.

As regards the date format, MySQL will not recognise the format you state. You will need to provide the dates in YYYY-MM-DD (or possibly unix timestamp) formats to MySQL.

Comment: Missed the [] on the $whereClauses.

Answer (score 1):

1)  No.  You're overwriting the string.  I think you mean $blah .= 'blah';

2)  Nope.  It won't be in quotes so MySQL will try to parse it as either a number or an entity name.  Then, if it were in quotes, it would be an invalidly formatted date for MySQL.

date() is your friend.

Oh, and also, in SQL it's 1 = 1, not 1 == 1.  And really that's not necessary to use here, though I guess it sort of makes the string building easier.  (I would probably build an array and implode it, but that would be slower/more complex.)

Answer (score 1):

1)   use "=" instead of  "=="

```
  $addQuery=" where 1==1";  =>  $addQuery=" where 1=1";
```

2) quote values properly if they are string or char type :

```
$addQuery=" and name=".$name; =>  $addQuery=" and name='".$name."'";
```

3)  check date formates in your database table and php variable make them same using `date_format()` or `date()`
functions.

4)if your want to check all condition at a time then do proper `concatenation` like:

```
   if($name>0) { $addQuery.=" and name=".$name; }
   if($date_start>0){ $addQuery.=" and date >=".$date_start; }
   ......
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append additional conditions to $addquery, so you must do as below :

```
    $addQuery .=" and name=".$name;
    $addQuery .=" and date >=".$date_start;
    $addQuery .=" and date<=".$date_end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

```
function get_sql($name = null, $date_start = null, $date_end = null)
{        
    $where = array();

    if($name !== null)
    {
        $where[] = "name='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'";
    }


    if($date_start !== null)
    {
        $where[] = "date >= STR_TO_DATE('".$date_start."', '%d/%m/%Y')";
    }

    if($date_end !== null)
    {
        $where[] = "date <= STR_TO_DATE('".$date_end."', '%d/%m/%Y')";
    }

    $query = "select * from TABLE_ARTICLE";

    if( count($where) > 0 ) {
        $query .= " WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $where);
    }

    return $query;
}
```